# warning for initialized enum variable : type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'etatCourant' [-Wimplicit-int]

Tags: c, enums, declaration, compiler-warnings

I'm having a warning when I tried to initialize my enum variable. Here is the code :

```
enum etatCourant {REPOS, MARCHE_AV, MARCHE_AR, ERREUR};
etatCourant = REPOS;
```

Here is the warning : type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'etatCourant' [-Wimplicit-int]

Am I missing something?

The code works as expected but I just don't like warnings. I try to avoid them as much as possible

Comment: This shouldn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/EMzjGrnE7

Comment: I can't reproduce - it sound like you are using an extremely outdated compiler from the previous millennium. Why are you doing that? Who told you to use it?

Comment: @Lundin I'm programming a STM32 nucleo board with STM32CubeIDE 1.12.1. I highly doubt the compiler is outdated but thanks

Comment: Types may not default to int since year 1999, so it ought to be outdated. You didn't answer which compiler you were using.

Comment: @Jabberwocky try C not C++, and place the declaration outside any function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to declare a variable with the name that coincides with the enumeration tag name without specifying a type specifier in the declaration of the variable

```
enum etatCourant {REPOS, MARCHE_AV, MARCHE_AR, ERREUR};
etatCourant = REPOS; 
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So according to the compiler message it supposes that by default it will have the type `int`.

If you want to declare a variable of the enumeration type you need to write for example

```
enum etatCourant {REPOS, MARCHE_AV, MARCHE_AR, ERREUR};
enum etatCourant courant = REPOS;
```

In this case the variable `courant` will have the enumeration type `enum etatCourant`.

Or the declaration may be rewritten also like

```
enum etatCourant etatCourant = REPOS;
```

though such a declaration can confuse readers of your code.

> The code works as expected but I just don't like warnings. I try to
> avoid them as much as possible

The code works as expected because in C enumerations belong to integer types and enumerators have the type `int`.

Comment: This shouldn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/EMzjGrnE7

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oh okay thank you very much. I forget it works like structures

Comment: @ClassyFied No at all. In C opposite to C++ structure, union and enumeration tag names are in different namespace than ordinary identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

In old style function declarations you can skip argument type. The compiler will consider it int:

```
enum etatCourant {REPOS, MARCHE_AV, MARCHE_AR, ERREUR};

void foo(etatCourant)
{
  etatCourant = REPOS; 
}

int main()
{
  int a=0;
  foo(a);
  return a;
}
```

compiler sees `foo` here as if its declared

```
void foo(int etatCourant);
```

Therefore you get the warning:

```
x.c:3:6: warning: type of ‘etatCourant’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
3 | void foo(etatCourant)
  |      ^~~
```

Just add type into your function declaration:

```
void foo(enum etatCourant etatCourant);
```

and the warning will go away.